# setTimeout form submit + problems on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```
setTimeout(function() { document.form_name.submit(); },1000);
```

it won't wort on google chrome.

gooogle chrome always see it as a popup and try to block it.

but if i do:

```
document.form_name.submit();
```

it work perfect.

could someone help me?

thx.

Comment: appears to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/SVQM8/ ?

Comment: @Niklas -- http://jsfiddle.net/SVQM8/2/ :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (assuming the form id is `'myForm'`):

```
setTimeout(function(){  
      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
  },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your form has `target` attribute set to `_blank`:

```
<form target="_blank">...</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVQM8/4/

Iceweasel also treats it like pop-up window.

Comment: Yes, remove `target="_blank"` from the form element and it should work.